# Java Date problems, finding the date X days ago

Tags: java, date

```
Date nowdate = new Date();
long nowms = nowdate.getTime();
long differencems = numdaysback * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;
long thenms = nowms - differencems;
Date thendate = new Date(thenms);
```

If numdaysback is 365, then I would suppose that thendate would be one year ago. but it's not... it's about three weeks ago?!?

```
NUMDAYSBACK: 365
NOWDATE: Wed Jun 22 20:31:58 SGT 2011
NOWMS: 1308745918625
DIFFERENCEMS: 1471228928
THENMS: 1307274689697
THENDATE: Sun Jun 05 19:51:29 SGT 2011
```

Comment: FYI, the terribly troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes built into Java 8 and later. See [*Tutorial* by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Answer (score 29, accepted):

How about:

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.add(Calendar.YEAR, -1);
Date thendate = cal.getTime();
```

Returns the same time of day regardless of DST or leap years, is shorter and clearer...

Generally `Calendar` is the way to go in such cases (unless you use a 3rd party library like Joda Time). You can use it for all kinds of calculations: add N days/hours/months/seconds, truncate time to a whole hour etc. - stuff that would be too much pain with `long` only.

Regarding your original question, it seems to be a victim of integer overflow. It works if the multiplication explicitly uses long:

```
long differencems = 365 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000L;
```

Comment: +1 for telling him what's wrong, instead of simply giving the solution.

Comment: FYI, the terribly troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes built into Java 8 and later. See [*Tutorial* by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Answer (score 7):

If you are using Java 8 and up, you can use the newer [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) library to do this a bit more cleanly.

```
Date xDaysAgo = Date.from( Instant.now().minus( Duration.ofDays( x ) ) );
```

Comment: Good Answer. Could be improved: (a) Explain that you are mixing the troublesome legacy class `Date` with the modern replacement, the *java.time* classes, to address the Question asking for a `Date` explicitly. (b) Explain that you are working in UTC with generic 24-hour chunks of time as a "day" without regard for the calendar/dates and without regard for time zones, as this seems to be what the Question is looking for.

Comment: Nearly correct. Across transitions to and from summer time (DST) of day is not 24 hours, which your code does not take into account (the code in the question has the same problem).

Answer (score 3):

Just try this:

```
long differencems = numdaysback * 24L * 60 * 60 * 1000;
```

With the new code you will not loose the digits due to integer multiplication.
Since we have marked the literal 24 as long, the multiplication will be done by auto converting the first operand numdaysback into long. The rest of the multiplication will also be done on long operands.

Answer (score 0):

This line:

```
long differencems = numdaysback * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;
```

the RHS should be: 31536000000. You have something much less, the reason being the RHS is being evaluated as an int (as all the quantities are ints), and you are exceeding MAX_INT. To correct to this:

```
long differencems = numdaysback * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000l;
```

Note the "l" which makes 1000 be a long - now the RHS will be evaluated as a long.

Comment: Thanks to everyone here. I am going with the calendar as you would all suggest.

Answer (score 0):

The `Date` class is (informally) deprecated. The API has so many faults, that it is really difficult to get Dates/Times right with it. The easiest example is something like your code for `differencems`. It fails, if the time inbetween contains a daylight savings switch (if you don't use UT) and will always fail to take care of leap seconds.

If your application depends on correct dates, you might want to use [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/).